# Is it safe to interrupt badblocks?

Tags: badblocks

I accidentally ran `badblocks` on my entire 320 GB disk instead of a single partition:

```
sudo badblocks -s -v -n -f /dev/sda
```

It's been running for 42 hours now. How can I tell when it will be finished? Can I interrupt it safely with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell when it will be finished?

You are using the `-v` (verbose) flag to `badblocks`. It should be constantly showing you:

```
xx.xx% done, xx:xx elapsed.
```

, from which you can easily estimate when it will finish.

> Can I interrupt it safely with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Yes.

Comment: Could it be continuate?

Comment: What is "continuate"? Do you mean "resumed"? Yes: look at the manpage, there is a way to specify the first block to check.

Comment: Ahhh yes, sorry for my bad english xD, Thank you very much :D